# Is it an undefined behavior to have different definitions of an inline function?

Tags: c++, inline, undefined-behavior, function-prototypes

Minimal code:

```
// --------inline.h--------
struct X { 
  static inline void foo ();
};   
#ifdef YES
inline void X::foo () { cout << "YES\n"; }
#else
inline void X::foo () { cout << "NO\n"; }
#endif

// --------file1.cpp--------
#define YES    // <---- 
#include"inline.h"
void fun1 ()
{
  X::foo();
}

// --------file2.cpp--------
#include"inline.h"
void fun2 ()
{
  X::foo();
}
```

If we call `fun1()` and `fun2()`, then they will print `YES` and `NO` respectively, which means they are referring different function bodies of same `X::foo()`.

Irrespective of this should be coded or not, my question is:
Is this a well defined or undefined behavior ?

Comment: If you would like to have two different free functions (not class members) in two different files but with the same name, then you can isolate them with the `static` keyword (or an anonymous namespace). Marking a function in file2.cpp as static means that no other .cpp file can see it during linking. That's useful for very large programs where you may not always be sure what common names have been taken up by functions already.

Comment: You don't really need inline.h and the #define hack in this case; just define "void X::foo()" (with or without the inline) one way in file1.cpp, and the other in file2.cpp, and you will have the exact same behavior.

Comment: @abarnert: Omitting the `inline` results in a different violation of the one definition rule. Non-inline functions are covered by 3.2 paragraph 3, inline functions by 3.2 paragraph 5. Many (most?) linkers catch the non-inline violations. Mine at least doesn't catch the inline violations.

Comment: @DavidHammen: As I said in the comments to Als's answer, it's effectively the same violation. 7.1.2 basically says that you can't use inline to get around the ODR (as well as a bunch of other things that aren't relevant here); the core problem is still the ODR (note the direct reference to 3.2 in 7.1.2). However, "it may also fool the compiler and/or linker into missing a good opportunity to warn you in this case".

Comment: @DavidHammen: Also, the main point is that you can get the exact same behavior by dropping the #define hack and putting the inline definitions in file1.cpp and file2.cpp, making for a much simpler "minimal code" demonstration.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes it is Undefined Behavior.

**Reference:**

C++03 Standard:

**7.1.2 Function specifiers [dcl.fct.spec]**
**Para 4:**

> **An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is used and shall have exactly the same definition in every case (3.2)**. [Note: a call to the inline function may be encountered before its definition appears in the translation unit. ] If a function with external linkage is declared inline in one translation unit, it shall be declared inline in all translation units in which it appears; no diagnostic is required. An
>   inline function with external linkage shall have the same address in all translation units. A static local variable in an extern inline function always refers to the same object. A string literal in an extern inline function is the same object in different translation units.

Note: 3.2 refers to the One Definition Rule, Which states:

**3.2 One definition rule    [basic.def.odr]**
**Para 1:**

> No translation unit shall contain more than one definition of any variable, function, class type, enumeration type or template.

Comment: +1. Also, note that inline is just a hint (although it may also fool the compiler and/or linker into missing a good opportunity to warn you in this case).

Comment: @abarnert: `inline` is much more than a hint.Whether the function call gets replaced with function body is at the discretion of the compiler but once you use `inline` the compiler **must** follow certain rules w.r.t One Definition Rule.

Comment: Yes, but what the rules effectively say is that using inline cannot get you around the ODR, except in the trivial sense that you can repeat the exact same definition.

Comment: @abarnert: That's not all. The rules also say that you must provide a definition in every translation unit where the function is (odr) used. So there are other extra requirements as well.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Yes, but that's not relevant to the OP's question.

Answer (score 7):

Undefined. You are violating ODR.

Answer (score 4):

> If we call fun1() and fun2(), then they will print YES and NO respectively, which means they are referring different function bodies of same X::foo().

Did you try it? With different optimization levels?

I get YES and NO, YES and YES, or NO and NO depending on the optimization level and the order in which the compiled objects are presented to the linker.

Needless to say, this is undefined behavior.

Comment: +1 for the this info. I din't notice that. I compiled with `-O4`.

Comment: @Als: Observing wildly varying behavior is good evidence (if not quite proof) of undefined behavior. It's the opposite that's dangerous (observing consistent behavior is not good evidence that it's not undefined behavior).

Comment: @Als: I realize observed behavior isn't proof. I knew this was UB beforehand. I thought it would be interesting to see what was produced, and to see how to toy around with it to make it produce different results.